# Write Array of String Arrays to File (txt,csv, etc)

Tags: java, arrays, csv, bufferedwriter

I have an Arraylist of String Arrays called NewArray.

```
ArrayList<String[]> NewArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

The data in NewArray looks somewhat like

```
[Vial1,Dest1]
[Vial2,Dest1]
[Vial3,Dest2]
[Vial4,Dest2]
```

I want to save this data, in this format (without the brackets) to a CSV/text file (with headers). The ideal output format would be:

```
VialNo,DestinationNo (these are the headers)
Vial1,Dest1
Vial2,Dest1
Vial3,Dest2
Vial4,Dest2
```

How would I use something like FileWriter to obtain that desired output in a txt/CSV file?

I've tried something like

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
for(String[] str: NewArray) {
  writer.write(str);
}
writer.close();
```

But I'm getting the error "The method write(int) in the type OutputStreamWriter is not applicable for the arguments (String[])"

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: Yeah.  We aren't a free code writing service for you.  Show what you were doing and what you can't figure out.

Comment: `str` isn't a string, its an array btw

Comment: Did you try to check what that error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // initialize
    ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    list.add(new String[] {"Vial1","Dest1"});
    list.add(new String[] {"Vial2","Dest2"});
    list.add(new String[] {"Vial3","Dest3"});
    list.add(new String[] {"Vial4","Dest4"});

    // writer
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 

    // headers
    writer.write("VialNo,DestinationNo\n");
    writer.flush();

    // data
    for(String[] arr: list) {
        String appender = "";
        for(String s : arr){
            writer.write(appender + s);
            appender = ",";
        }
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

This gave me the output

```
VialNo,DestinationNo
Vial1,Dest1
Vial2,Dest2
Vial3,Dest3
Vial4,Dest4
```

You need to loop over each string in each array, not try to simply print out the array. I also used an appender for formatting the file as a csv.

***Updated code to include creating the headers***

Comment: Updated the answer so it creates the headers as well.

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you loop through your array and always write a line. Better put your writer in a using, so you don't have to bother with closing and flushing Streams, Writers etc.
If you actually want to save the object and not just write the content of the array down, then take a look at the serializer which outputs the object as xml which you can save to a file and load through a deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted answer didn't work for someone (didn't for me). Try this for
ArrayList of specific class types foe example ArrayList tester = new ArrayList();

public class PassDataToFile {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {

    RSSFeedParser parser = new RSSFeedParser("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologysectorNews");
    Feed feed = parser.readFeed();

    String input = "C:\\Users\\Special\\workspace\\demo.txt";
    File newFile = new File(input);

    if (!newFile.exists()){
        newFile.createNewFile();
    }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        int sx = feed.getMessages().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++) {

            writer.write(feed.getMessages().get(i).toString() + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("File successfully written into "  + input);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File writing operation failed ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}